# How can I clear history and settings for the Remote Desktop Viewer (Vinagre)?

Tags: configuration, remote-desktop, vinagre

How do I clear all the settings for Vinagre to take it back to a brand-new, virgin state? I accidentally typed a connection in wrong and I cannot figure out how to delete it.  Also some of my connections are not working correctly and I think that if I could flush the whole thing clean it might fix those issues.  I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but it remembers the previous settings/connections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it here:
~/.local/share/vinagre/history

Open it with your favorite text editor and go to town or simply delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

simple find the configuration files with this command :

```
find . -name vinagre
```

easy :)

Comment: That will only find files whose names are exactly `vinagre` (and which are somewhere contained within the current directory). Unless all Vinagre configuration files are stored inside a directory called `vinagre` (perhaps inside `~/.config`), this is unlikely to work. A better way would be to search for files in the home directory with `vinagre` in their names (and to allow capitalization, too): `find ~ -iname \*vinagre\*`