# How to clear Vinagre recent connections?

Tags: filesystem, vinagre

How do I clear the items in Vinagre under `Remote > Recent Connections`?

I've done [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146465/how-can-i-clear-history-and-settings-for-the-remote-desktop-viewer-vinagre) and it does not work.  I've deleted the entire Vinagre profile directory `~/.local/share/vinagre` and it somehow regenerates the recent connections list.  I uninstalled and reinstall Vinagre... *still there!*

Where the heck is this stubborn list stored that I can actually delete it?

Answer (score 0):

[Found it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417787/how-to-clear-recent-history-in-xubuntu-12-04)

Delete the file `$HOME/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`